# Magento - How to translate the module mini-form search

Tags: magento

I want to translate the default input text of the mini-form (search) to german. The original text is "Search entire store here..." and it is situated in "default/default/template/cataloguesearch/form.mini.phtml"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi this grep will help you out and you can always use inline translation tool that Magento offers.

You are looking the following file app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv

```
$ grep 'Search' app/locale/ -rsn


app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:360:"Global Record Search","Global Record Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:361:"Global Search","Global Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:433:"Last 5 Search Terms","Last 5 Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:533:"New Search","New Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:778:"Search","Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:779:"Search Index","Search Index"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:780:"Search Term","Search Term"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:781:"Search Terms","Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv:957:"Top 5 Search Terms","Top 5 Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:27:"Add New Search Term","Add New Search Term"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:131:"Catalog Seo Popular Search Terms","Catalog Seo Popular Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:137:"Catalog, Search","Catalog, Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:208:"Delete Search","Delete Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:228:"Edit Search","Edit Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:229:"Edit Search '%s'","Edit Search '%s'"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:355:"New Search","New Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:510:"Save Search","Save Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:514:"Search","Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:515:"Search Engine Optimizations","Search Engine Optimizations"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:516:"Search Information","Search Information"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:517:"Search Query","Search Query"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:518:"Search Term with such search query already exists.","Search Term with such search query already exists."
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:519:"Searchable","Searchable"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:656:"Use In Search Results Layered Navigation","Use In Search Results Layered Navigation"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:664:"Use in Advanced Search","Use in Advanced Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv:667:"Use in Quick Search","Use in Quick Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Reports.csv:129:"Search Query","Search Query"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Reports.csv:130:"Search Terms","Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv:209:"Search Engines Optimization","Search Engines Optimization"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Api.csv:119:"Global Record Search","Global Record Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Api.csv:144:"Last 5 Search Terms","Last 5 Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Api.csv:287:"Top 5 Search Terms","Top 5 Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:3:"Advanced Search","Advanced Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:4:"Advanced Search Form","Advanced Search Form"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:5:"Advanced Search Result","Advanced Search Result"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:8:"Apply Layered Navigation if Search Results are Less Than","Apply Layered Navigation if Search Results are Less Than"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:9:"Attribute setting change related with Search Index. Please run <a href=""%s"">Rebuild Search Index</a> process.","Attribute setting change related with Search Index. Please run <a href=""%s"">Rebuild Search Index</a> process."
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:11:"Catalog Advanced Search","Catalog Advanced Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:12:"Catalog Search","Catalog Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:13:"Catalog Search Index","Catalog Search Index"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:23:"Maximum Search query  length is %s. Your query was cut.","Maximum Search query  length is %s. Your query was cut."
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:25:"Minimum Search query length is %s","Minimum Search query length is %s"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:30:"Popular Search Terms","Popular Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:31:"Quick Search Form","Quick Search Form"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:35:"Search","Search"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:36:"Search Settings","Search Settings"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:37:"Search Terms","Search Terms"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:38:"Search Type","Search Type"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:39:"Search entire store here...","Search entire store here..."
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:40:"Search results for '%s'","Search results for '%s'"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:41:"Search results for: '%s'","Search results for: '%s'"
app/locale/en_US/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv:42:"Search:","Search:"
```